# AJAX radio buttons don't work

Tags: ajax, jquery, radio-button

Alright so I have a pair of radio buttons that are to store their values into a database in order to retain their state when the user returns to the site in the future. The thing is, whether the user chooses button 1 (like) or button 2 (dislike) the value is always returned as like. Can anyone help me figure out why dislike isn't being returned?

Here is my form.php:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
var entered = document.getElementById('entered').value;
var queryString = "?entered=" + entered;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "check.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>

<form name="myform" action="check.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Posts</legend>

<div id="post_1" class="post">
    <b>Post #1</b><br>
    Content of post #1<br>
    <p><input type="radio" id="entered" name="like_1" value="like" onclick="ajaxFunction();" onchange="ajaxFunction();" /><label for="like1a">Like</label></p> <p><input type="radio" id="entered" name="like_1" value="dislike" onclick="ajaxFunction();" onchange="ajaxFunction();" /><label for="like1b"> Dislike</label></p>
</div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
```

and this is check.php:

```
<?php
// Retrieve data from Query String
$entered = $_GET['entered'];
// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$entered = mysql_real_escape_string($entered);
echo $entered;
?>
```

So basically $entered is only storing "like" no matter which radio button is selected and changing the selection should change the value stored, but that doesn't happen either. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is generally inadvisable to have a radio button submit something, you should probably make it a regular button.

Comment: Also, you should add CSRF protection for your site if it will ever be deployed.

Comment: the user should only be allowed to select like OR dislike, not both. As far as I know, only radio buttons can do that.

Comment: Right, but clicking a radio button should not submit it, there should be another button to keep with the expected behavior of a radio button. Also, you could have a button that says "Like" and when you press it, it changes to a "Dislike"

Comment: but the point is to give the user a choice. To make the user press the button twice in order to dislike something makes no sense. Check boxes don't do it either because the user should not be able to like AND dislike something. The only logical option is a radio button pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        var buttonSelected = this.id.replace(valueSelected + '_','');
        //alert('Button Selected: ' + buttonSelected + "\nValue Selected: " + valueSelected);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/test.php?entered=' + valueSelected + '&id=' + buttonSelected,
            data:  '',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#ajaxDiv').html(result);
            },
            error: function (response, desc, exception) {
                // custom error
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>
<fieldset>
<legend>Posts</legend>
    <div>
        <h1>Post #1</h1>
        <div>Content of post #1</div>
        <input type="radio" id="like_1" value="like" name="action1" class="button" /> <label for="like_1">Like</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="dislike_1" value="dislike" name="action1" class="button" /> <label for="dislike_1">Dislike</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Post #2</h1>
        <div>Content of post #2</div>
        <input type="radio" id="like_2" value="like" name="action2" class="button" /> <label for="like_2">Like</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="dislike_2" value="dislike" name="action2" class="button" /> <label for="dislike_2">Dislike</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="ajaxDiv">Your result will display here</div>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php

echo 'ID selected: ' . $_GET['id'] . ' - Value selected: ' . $_GET['entered'];
```

Comment: you're forgetting that my code needs to save the selected value to the database so it isn't enough to have the page stay onto itself... I don't see where this goes to 'store' the value into a php variable on check.php...

Comment: in your code, you reference document.getElementById('entered').value; and then you have 2 input with the same ID. therefore it pick 1, you will have to give a different ID to the second one and then check if the first one is checked, then use the value, otherwise use the second value.

Comment: aah, that makes sense. Here's the twist however. These pairs of buttons will be attached to blog posts whose ID's are generated by wordpress. As such, the IDs of the buttons will be id="like-<?php the_ID(); ?>" and id="dislike-<?php the_ID(); ?>".

My problem is, how can I get the javascript to recognize these IDs? I can put the javascript in the blog's post generating loop but wouldn't that be inefficient?

Comment: I updated my code. On your radio you will have to use "this" and the value to the "like_1" for ID 1, and "dislike_1" for dislike 1. Then you don't have to use the ID of the element and do a for loop.

Comment: So I'm trying to make your code work but there's a problem: When I select "like" or dislike" instead of displaying what my selection was in the ajaxDiv, it is repeating the form!

When the page loads, it give me one set of options. When I make my choice, I get the same set of options repeated! and so on... I'm supposed to receive a simple text inside the ajaxDiv stating the value of the radio buttton through check.php.

Comment: That is strange, I use this code in FF and it works good. Do you absolutely need to use native JS? can use jQuery?

Comment: I can use jquery if the code works, otherwise I know nothing about it. For some reason the logic behind jQuery escapes me.

Comment: View my updated code using jQuery. I also added my test.php as example.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work. I've spent a week on this and nothing. The main file is test.php and the output should send to check.php 

This is such a headache!

Comment: Can you tell me what does not work, any errors? I just tried with FF 6 and i get "ID selected: 1 - Value selected: dislike" when I check Content of post #1 - Dislike

Answer (score 0):

When you get an element by an ID, it only returns one element, and which one is arbitrary because there should only be one element per ID. Instead, read the checked attribute to figure out which radio button is checked.

```
var entered=null;
var arr=document.getElementsByName("like_1");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].checked){
        entered=arr[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code broke my ajax. selecting a radio button brings the page to a blank check.php in the browser...

Comment: Question: This pair of radio buttons will be attached to posts in a blog. The post IDs are set by the blog as they are posted in the blog's loop. The radio buttons will be named 
name="like_<?php the_ID(); ?>" 
and
name="dislike_<?php the_ID(); ?>"

I can't get the javascript to find the names of the buttons. Shuld I be putting the javascript inside the loop? This strikes me as inefficient and load-bearing. Is there a way to get it to work by keeping the javascript inside the header?